# scala: class can't access companion object members externally

Tags: scala

As follows I have defined a MapModel class and its companion companion object.

```
class MapModel(val map: Map[String, Double])

object MapModel {
  implicit def MapToMapModel(map: Map[String, Double]) = new MapModel(map)

  def apply(map: Map[String, Double]) = new MapModel(map)

  /**
    * weighted sum
    *
    * @param other
    * @param weight
    * @return
    */
  def +*(other: MapModel, weight: Double): MapModel = {
    ???
  }
  def test(): Unit ={

  }
}
```

I want to create a MapModel instance and call the +* method. However all methods in the companion object can not be found.
For example, I have a `jm` instance which is a `Map[String,Double]`,

```
MapModel(jm).test()
```

produces error, saying

> value test is not a member of MapModel

Comment: Companion object's members should be accessed directly, like `MapModel.test()`

Comment: So companion object is not an instance of the class?

Comment: The companion object is a singleton instance of the class. `MapModel(jm)` invokes the `apply()` method of the companion object which, in this case, is a factory method returning an instance of `MapModel`. Since `test()` is a method on the object, not the class, it can't be invoked on the factory method's return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods defined on the companion object of a class/trait are not visible on any *instance* of the type, but only via the invocation of a method explicitly on the companion itself.

It seems like you're looking for an extension method like syntax. You can do so via an `implicit class`:

```
implicit class MapModelOps(val mapModel: MapModel) extends AnyVal {
  def +*(other: MapModel, weight: Double): MapModel = {
    ???
  }
}
```

And now this works:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val map = MapModel(Map("s" -> 1.0))
  val res = map +* (MapModel(Map("v" -> 2.0)), 3.0)
}
```

Alternatively, if you have access to the underlying class, you can just put the method inside it.

Comment: Yuval, if Tyler controls the companion object, it means he also controls the main class. In which case, why `+*` should be implemented as an extension method rather than a method inside the `MapModel` itself as Nicolas does?

Comment: @SergGr That's why I commented in the bottom that it's up to him. It's a matter of style IMO, depends how you want to do it, both ways would work.

Answer (score 1):

The object `MapModel` doesn't have the type `MapModel` (confusingly enough, it has the type `MapModel.type`).

If you want to add methods to `MapModel`, you need to add them to the class. Your `+*` method, for example, makes very little sense in the companion object:

```
class MapModel(val map: Map[String, Double]) {
  def +*(other: MapModel, weight: Double): MapModel = new MapModel(map ++ other)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can be useful to give access to all companion object members using the class instances. It can be achieved using following implicit conversion:

```
implicit def mapModelAcessCompanion(m: MapModel): MapModel.type = MapModel
```